# Get list of forwarded ports

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, vagrant

My system has several port forwarding settings active. Among others, I have some Vagrant machines with port-forwarding configured:

```
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 33022
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 33080
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 33443
  end
```

I have several machines with port forwarding configured, and other tools doing port forwarding (`ssh` ...). I would like to verify that the system config is as expected.

Is there some way to list all these port forwarding rules?

Comment: How about `iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING -n -v` (will require privilege)?

Comment: @MadHatter Not showing the port forwarders ...

Answer (score -1):

Haven't worked much with vagrant before, but you could use

```
netstat -tulpen
```

to list all port bindings and their associated process.

Comment: port forwarding in iptables does not have listening ports.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I shouldn't answer here while still half asleep :/